# Uploading direct video with MUX

Tags: php, api, coldfusion, mux-video

I am going with the Docs API to do a direct Upload with Mux, But cannot seems to find any one solid example where I have to select the from my local, say one mp4 file of size 100 MB and once I click the submit button, it should call the MUX to upload at least the headers and then webhook can keep doing its work, but all I see is the examples they have is passing the URL to it and then the webhooks can be called?

This is really confusing, in every post I searched they had written it can be done but how they have not shown it anywhere

anyone who can guide in this

Thanks

Comment: Do you plan to use php or Coldfusion?

Comment: i can use any one of them as long as work is complete, here is a small update i tried doing it but no luck

Comment: this is my try https://pastebin.com/JeRfr98b

Comment: @Jhing You need to post your code here, either PHP or ColdFusion, not link to an external site. Make sure to not post any access keys to their API.